# Implement BroadCastReceiver upon receiving a new SMS

Tags: android, notifications, sms, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to implement Broadcast receiver to implement notification pop-up upon SMS received on my Android device. However I have set a condition to detect only specific SMSs from pre-defined senders and then pop-up a notification. Here is what I have coded till now :

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    private static final String TAG = "MyBroadCastReceiver";
     String str = "";
     static Context context;
     String sender;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) 
    {

//      Log.i(TAG,"OnReceive ++      ");
        Bundle bndl = arg1.getExtras();
        SmsMessage[] msg = null;

        if (null != bndl)
        {
            //---retrieve the SMS message received---
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bndl.get("pdus");
            msg = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];

            if(msg[0].getOriginatingAddress().endsWith("AIRMTA") ||
               msg[0].getOriginatingAddress().endsWith("ICICIB") || 
               msg[0].getOriginatingAddress().endsWith("FCHRGE") ||
               msg[0].getOriginatingAddress().endsWith("MYAMEX") ||
               msg[0].getOriginatingAddress().endsWith("MOBIKW") ||
               msg[0].getOriginatingAddress().endsWith("OLACAB") ||
               msg[0].getOriginatingAddress().endsWith("HDFCB")  ||
               msg[0].getOriginatingAddress().endsWith("AIRMNY") 
               )
            {
                for (int i=0; i<msg.length; i++)
                {
                    msg[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);             
//                  str += "SMS From " + msg[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                    sender = msg[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                    str += " :\r\n";
                    str += msg[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                    str += "\n";
                    context = arg0;
                }


            //---display incoming SMS as a Android Toast---
//            Toast.makeText(arg0, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            //---Create a status bar notification for incoming sms-->
            int mNotificationId = 001;
            NotificationCompat.Builder  mBuilder = new   NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
            mBuilder.setContentTitle(sender);
            mBuilder.setContentText(str);
            mBuilder.setTicker("New Message Alert!");
            mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification);

            Intent resultIntent  = new Intent(arg0, MainActivity.class);
            PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(arg0, 0, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

            NotificationManager mNotifyMgr = (NotificationManager) arg0.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            mNotifyMgr.notify(mNotificationId, mBuilder.build());

            MapsFragment obj = new MapsFragment();
            obj.initilizeMap();
        }
        }

    }
}
```

Unfortunately the application is crashing every time I receive an SMS, be it from any sender. I am not able to understand what is going wrong with the code !
Can anyone help me out on this ?

Here is the log cat error report :

```
Process: com.techfrk.fetchinboxsms, PID: 21956
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.techfrk.fetchinboxsms.MyBroadcastReceiver: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.telephony.SmsMessage.getOriginatingAddress()' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2616)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:151)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1380)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
```

Answer (score 1):

You get a `NullPointerException` exception because your msg array is always empty when calling `msg[0].getOriginatingAddress().endsWith()`. 
With `msg = new SmsMessage[pdus.length]` you create an empty array with the size of `pdus.length` but this does not add any objects to it.

Instead of

```
if(msg[0].getOriginatingAddress().endsWith("AIRMTA") ||
           msg[0].getOriginatingAddress().endsWith("ICICIB") || 
           msg[0].getOriginatingAddress().endsWith("FCHRGE") ||
           msg[0].getOriginatingAddress().endsWith("MYAMEX") ||
           msg[0].getOriginatingAddress().endsWith("MOBIKW") ||
           msg[0].getOriginatingAddress().endsWith("OLACAB") ||
           msg[0].getOriginatingAddress().endsWith("HDFCB")  ||
           msg[0].getOriginatingAddress().endsWith("AIRMNY") 
           )
        {
            for (int i=0; i<msg.length; i++)
            {
                msg[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);             
                // str += "SMS From " + msg[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                sender = msg[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                str += " :\r\n";
                str += msg[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                str += "\n";
                context = arg0;
            }
}
```

you should do something like

```
SmsMessage[] messages = Telephony.Sms.Intents.getMessagesFromIntent(arg1);

if(messages.length < 1) return;

SmsMessage sms = messages[0];
sender = sms.getOriginatingAddress();
str = sms.getMessageBody().toString();

if (sms.getOriginatingAddress().endsWith("AIRMTA")) { // add all your needed statements
    // show your notification
}
```

Please keep in mind that this code is extremely simplified for a better understanding.

Comment: Okey. So then how can I make it add objects automatically as messages are received ?

Comment: I have edited my post and added a short code example ;)

Comment: The code is not workng. It is showing an error in createFromPdu. Here is the error : The method createFromPdu(byte[]) in the type SmsMessage is not applicable for the arguments (byte)

Comment: Oh yeah, there was a typo in there - it should be `SmsMessage.createFromPdu(pdus)` .

Comment: The code is still giving me error. I have updated my code below with the edits !

Comment: I have edited the code once again and added some more comments for you ;)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However Eclipse is not able to recognize Telephony in  Telephony.Sms.Intents.getMessagesFromIntent(arg1);